# android studio で constraint layout の textviewなどが表示されない

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

タイトルの通りなのですが、android studio で constraint layout の textviewなどをドラッグアンドドロップしてもUIに表示されません。
PCのスペック的ものなのでしょうか。教えてください。
i5-6200U / 8G

Answer (score -1):

おそらく私も同じようなスペックで問題が起きていました。
理由はわかりませんが、AppThemeのところをNoTitleBarにすると解決しました。